# Failed to Authenticate apt upgrade

Tags: release-loki, updates, apt

Command run: sudo apt upgrade

```
[sudo] password for user:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libllvm3.8 libmircommon5 libvala-0.34-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libvala-0.36-0 linux-headers-4.10.0-35 linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic
linux-signed-image-4.10.0-35-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
apparmor apparmor-profiles apparmor-utils appcenter bind9-host bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cups-ppdc dnsutils ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0
gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs libapparmor-perl libapparmor1 libbind9-140 libbluetooth3 libcryptsetup4
libdns-export162 libdns162 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgs9 libgs9-common libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140
liblouis-data liblouis9 liblwres141 libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib libscratchcore0 libsmbclient
libvirt-bin libvirt0 libwbclient0 libwingpanel-2.0-0 libxml2 libxml2:i386 libxml2-utils linux-doc linux-firmware linux-generic-hwe-16.04
linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-libc-dev linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04 pantheon-greeter
python3-apparmor python3-libapparmor python3-louis python3.5 python3.5-minimal qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
samba-libs scratch-text-editor snapd switchboard-plug-networking tcpdump wingpanel wingpanel-indicator-network xserver-common
82 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,464 kB/225 MB of archives.
After this operation, 316 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libvala-0.36-0 libscratchcore0 scratch-text-editor wingpanel libwingpanel-2.0-0 pantheon-greeter switchboard-plug-networking
wingpanel-indicator-network appcenter
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] n
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

What I did to try to fix it. Reimported keys. Removed apt caches and such and reran sudo apt update which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for some persons like said above:

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt update
```

resolved the problem

for others:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

resolved the problem

So try the first, if it doesn't resolve the problem try the second way

inform us ^^

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-key update
$ sudo apt-get update
```